# Error when creating new project with older version laravel. What should i do?

Tags: laravel

i'm new in laravel. I neede help with creating new project with laravel version 5.8.
I used this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.8.*" LaravelProject
```

But,

```
[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.8.* in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.
```

Note: php version is 8.0.9

Comment: still have the same error

Comment: you can't use Laravel 5.8 with PHP 8  ... https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/composer.json#L11 ... composer won't install it since it doesn't meet the PHP requirement set on the project

Comment: make sure u have `composer` and php version  `^7.1.3`

Comment: composer already installed in xampp/php folder

Comment: @lagbox my superior demand me to use 5.8. What should i do ? Should i downgrade php ?

Comment: @lagbox thanks. I installed older xampp and it works now

Comment: Please be aware that laravel 5.8 is way past it's LTS expiration date.
This means this version of laravel is not supported, nor will it receive security updates.
Considering it's a new project, you really should try to convince your superior to upgrade to a newer version. Composer packages for laravel are unlikely to support this version too, resulting in more problems (and outdated packages) down the line.

Comment: @Tropus Noted, thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks lagbox,

Turn out newest version of xampp PHP didn't support Laravel 5.8.
Installing older version of xampp does the trick.